# MVC project doesnt work fine in deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have a MVC ASP.NET project, when i run it in my laptop its works fine, but when i make a deploy to the server, some thing doesnt works, i pass my solution to the server and install the VS for debugging here and when i run it from VS it´s works fine, but if i publish de page, i doesnt work.

here is the view

_layout.cshtml

```
           <div class = "brand" style = "width:10%;text-align:center; max-height:40px">                      
                     <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" style = "color:#DDDDDD;text-align:center;margin:auto auto auto auto">
                         @if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                         {
                             Html.RenderAction("Imagen","Home");
                         }
                     </a>   
                </div>
```

my method "Imagen" from my controller "Home"

```
public ActionResult Imagen()
    {
        usuarios usuario = CashControl.usuarios.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
        usuarios usur = new usuarios();
        usur.imagen = usuario.imagen;
        return PartialView("Imagen",usur);
    }
```

my partial view Imagen.cshtml

```
@model CashControl.Models.usuarios
<img src="../uploads/@Model.imagen" />
```

Note: the projects works fine in local, but in deployment not, dont display the image because the model returns null :/, i view the html code in the firebug and the route for the image is

```
  <img src="../uploads/" />
```

Comment: I am assuming you are using a different database when you deploy your solution. Is there data in the 'imagen' field?

Comment: the database is the same, i use the same database in the deploy and develop

Comment: the field has a value, if run from VS show the image but in the deploy not showing it :/

Comment: it probably has to do with the path. Most likely in dev, the project is running under a virtual directory, http://localhost:PORTNUMBER/VirtualDirectory but when deployed it is running under root, so the "../" would be incorrect

Comment: that isn´t the problem, i prove put the query in code "../uploads/img.png" and works, the problem is the control returns e empty or null model :/

Comment: The "usuarios" static property is returning a "usuario" with null "imagen" and you are associating that to your new instance. See if your production database has indeed the user image name and make sure it is populated.

Comment: the producction database its the same as using in the develop, it has information because when i run it from VS (the VS is installed in the same server) it shows the image, but when i deployed the image isn´t show, if i check the html in the firebug, the "Model.Image" is empty and the URL are "../uploads/" :/

Comment: visual studio has a habit that trips many people up, where it actually creates a copy of the database in the project deployment directories.  i.e. a different database when you build in debug mode vs release mode.  Can you post your connection strings so we can see where your database actually lives?

Comment: the Database lives, because i login in the webpage to access to the main site, so the database lives